# Increase div to one direction using css only

Tags: html, css

I have this code that I need the div to resize vertically as the text inside increases. The bottom should remain fixed as div increases upwards

```
<div class ="div-increase">commodo sit amet, posuere lobortis quam. Vestibulum d
</div>
```

How can I achieve this using css

```
.div-increase{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 210px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 210px;
    max-height: 250px;
    min-height: 1.5em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: normal;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think you have specify what you exactly want to achieve. It's not quite clear from your description

Comment: Normally, the div will expand in size vertically and horizontally as text is increased. I need the bottom not to increase, remain fixed and then the rest of the div to increase upwards as text is added

Comment: you can simply use position: fixed & bottom: 0,
check out this: https://jsfiddle.net/r95g6o1t

Comment: This worked well for me. Post the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using flexbox with `flex-direction: column-reverse`. I've also made the div editable, so you can try the snippet typing some extra text:

```css
.div-increase {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  width: 210px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 210px;
  max-height: 250px;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-increase" contenteditable="true">commodo sit amet, posuere lobortis quam. Vestibulum d
</div>
```

here is my favorite flexbox [cheat-sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), the official [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model) and [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: What you write is just a div with reversed content and I think it's not what @kevinRobert want.